# touch events on UIimageView which is on UIwindow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitouch, uiwindow

I m using UIimageview on top of UIWindow. I want to handle touch event for that Imageview, but m not able to do it.

When i use UIimageView on UIview, we can use touchBegan, touchEnded but how to handle it when it is on UIWindow instead of UIView.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to handle the tap, you have to set,

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

By default *UIImageView* has the *userInteractionEnabled* property set to *NO*. And you can add a tap gesture recognizer to it,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(anyMethod)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
[tgr release];
```

If you want to move the image, you can use *UIPanGestureRecognizer*.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

try this function